# Nodejs how to access a property of an object

Tags: node.js

I need help to access a property of a object that is a instance with the require.

```
t = require('./a');
```

FILE a.js

```
module.exports = {
 var1: 0,
 method1:function(){
    a=function(){
      console.log(this.var1);
    }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access the property like you would a local Object.

```
var t = require('./a')

var localVar1 = t.var1
console.log(localVar1) // => Outputs: 0

t.method1() // => Outputs: 0
```